# How to restructure code to avoid warning: "Adapting argument list by creating a 2-tuple"

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The following code has already been *verified as working* as I want it: i.e. adding a tuple to an existing sequence (also of tuples)

```
iter.map { r =>     // Iterator of org.apache.spark.sql.Row
   r.toSeq :+ (outColName,locMap(r.getAs[String](inColName)))
}
```

However our build system has `fail on warning` enabled and thus errors out the above code with:

```
[info] 'compiler-interface' not yet compiled for Scala 2.10.6. Compiling...
[info]   Compilation completed in 24.504 s
[error] /home/../Sampling.scala:40: Adapting argument list 
         by creating a 2-tuple: this may not be what you want.
[error]         signature: SeqLike.:+[B >: A, That](elem: B)(implicit bf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Repr,B,That]): That
[error]   given arguments: outColName, locMap(r.getAs[String](inColName))
[error]  after adaptation: SeqLike.:+((outColName, locMap(r.getAs[String](inColName))): (String, Int))
[error]           r.toSeq :+ (outColName,locMap(r.getAs[String](inColName)))
[error]                   ^
[error] one error found
```

Now - as mentioned - this *is* what I want.  But `Travis` needs to be made happy. So what is the correct invocation to signfify the same -i.e. this is the desired behavior - and avoid the warnings here?

Comment: what's the type of r?

Comment: @marios updated op

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to help the compiler by explicitly adding the method invocation and the parenthesis.

```
iter.map { r: Row => 
   r.toSeq.:+( (outColName,locMap(r.getAs[String](inColName))):Any )
}
```

Comment: Just looked more carefullly at your suggestion: it is not correct. r is a `Row`. The other suggestion - to be explicit on `.:+` has no effect. Same errors.

Comment: So this didn't do the trick? I changed the def of r to Row. From the error message it looked to me like a compiler warning on not being sure if you are calling :+ with two arguments (a,b) or you are calling it with one argument of type tuple (a,b).

Comment: no that's not the issue at all.  The 2tuple is correct and the original code does work. the problem is our `Travis` requires no *warnings*.

Comment: Oh yes, I am not arguing about correctness, is all about the warning and how to make it go away.

Comment: so  the suggestion *was* tried and same error as in OP

Comment: k: will get back when i can change that code - probably 3 or 4 days

Comment: Np, take your time

Comment: How did it go ?

Comment: I'm looking at the code now - which has been compiling: I don't remember what I changed to get it to work . But i'll give upvote for now.